# GCP alerting with custom labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to set up an alert policy on Google Cloud Monitoring to fire when a certain threshold of `5xx` requests on Cloud Run revisions with a label of `prod = true` is met, but can't find the filter needed to meet that last condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Cloud Monitoring?  If yes, then it appears you can set a filter as shown here ... https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters

I'd bring up the Cloud Monitoring Metrics explorer and start fiddling around there until you see a metric displayed metrics that includes only 5xx requests with a label called prod with a value of true.   Maybe describe what you have tried and what you have found?

Comment: Yes! I'm using Cloud Monitoring. Sorry for my lack of clarity. I've been toying with Metrics Explorer with CLOUD RUN REVISION - REQUEST COUNT as Resource & Metric, with filter response_code_class == 5xx, but couldn't find a field to input my custom labels. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to run by creating a log-based metric in Cloud Logging, as I couldn't find the filter needed in Cloud Monitoring. Then I created an alert policy when a certain threshold is met. Also, regex doesn't apply to httpRequest.status as it is an integer field, not string, so I had to compromise and make it filter by status = 500, not 5xx.

Query I made is:

```
resource.type = "cloud_run_revision" AND labels.prod = "true" AND httpRequest.status = 500
```